# Choosing 15 colors from a 159 color palette to recolor (quantize) an image

Tags: java, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

My question is, what is the best way to use imagemagick (or a java library) to recolor an image using only 15 colors chosen from a 159 color static palette.  I would use those 15 colors to create 15_color_palette.png and use the remap function of imagemagick convert to recolor the image.

```
convert input.png +dither -remap 15_color_palette.png output.png
```

I've tried a couple of different methods, but neither of them work well enough (at least I think that they could do better -- I guess it's possible that there are no better method).

**Example 1:**

```
convert input.png +dither -colors 15 work/15_color.png
convert work/15_color.png -unique-colors work/15_color_palette.png
convert work/15_color_palette.png -remap work/palette.png work/15_color_palette_converted.png 
convert input.png +dither -remap work/15_color_palette_converted.png work/final.png
```

(this one chooses 15 colors from all colors, remaps that to palette 15 colors from the 159 color palette palette and then uses those 15 colors to recolor the original image).

**Example 2:**

```
convert +dither -remap work/palette.png work/remap.png
#use java to count top 15 colors used from the remap, recolor the original using those 15 colors
convert +dither -remap work/temp_palette.png work/final.png
```